# Writing a log file for Protractor/Jasmine tests without using command line

Tags: logging, automation, jasmine, protractor

I'm aware that if you were to do something like `protractor config.js > file.log` all the console output would be written to file.log.

Is there a way to do this/access that output from within the tests though so that I can use a dynamic path that's created with my reporting tool? And also in a way that I don't lose the console output.

Edits:

To elaborate a little further, I'm not **only** interested in `console.log` output.  I'm interested in everything that comes from what seems to be protractors `testLogger`.  For example, at the end of a suite's execution I am presented with:

    `[13:19:37] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
    [13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-0 failed 4 test(s)
    [13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-1 failed 1 test(s)
    [13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-2 failed 1 test(s)
    [13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-3 failed 1 test(s)
    [13:19:37] I/launcher - overall: 7 failed spec(s)`

I would like that in addition to the other console output.

Comment: Can you expand more on what you need from the console.output .. Because console output generates result for the corresponding spec only after the spec is completely executed. So what information do you want to access from spec at run-time ?

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that, but what i'm looking for is quite literally whatever the output of the console reads written to a file by some command within my tests and not the console command ' > test.log'

I guess a simpler question is how does protractor write to the console in the first place?

Comment: I would suggest an approach to use custom logging then instead of `console.log` ..  Check below below solution ..

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help if you are looking for console solution

Comment: I'm not only looking for console.log items.  When a suite finishes I'm left with something like: 

`[13:19:37] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-0 failed 4 test(s)
[13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-1 failed 1 test(s)
[13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-2 failed 1 test(s)
[13:19:37] I/launcher - internet explorer #01-3 failed 1 test(s)
[13:19:37] I/launcher - overall: 7 failed spec(s)`

That is the information I would like to write to a file along with console.log statements if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is instead of writing any required information to console and trying to make your reporter read it, I would suggest you to implement logging from your tests to get better control.

Instead of a `console.log()` - have something like `logger().info("Testing Log4js")` and then make your reporter operate on it.

If you are further interested there is js version of `log4j` called - [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) that I tried with Protractor and its works fine.

In case you are further interested here is the link to [implementation examples](http://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/04/how-to-implements-logs-for-protractorjavascript-based-test-automation-frameworks)

Comment: It's a nice informative post. It would be great if you could help me in below mentioned stuffs

1) How we can delete the application logs before we run every protractor est automatically.
2) How can we integrate this with 'log4js-protractor-appender' because this resolves the promises which is passes as an argument. This is absent in log4j

Comment: @hello_abhishek .. I have answered your questions in the new post that you raised. Please let me know if you are looking for more info

Comment: link to implementation examples is dead

Answer (score 0):

**Complete code example for reference:**

Steps to setup log4js for Protractor framework

Step 1: Install log4js npm module

Step 2: Create a helper js file – which will create the logger object which can be imported to tests

```
'use strict';
var log4js = require('log4js');
var log4jsGen = {
    getLogger: function getLogger() {
        log4js.loadAppender('file');
        log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file('./logs/ExecutionLog.log'), 'logs');
        var logger = log4js.getLogger('logs');
        return logger;
    }
};

module.exports = log4jsGen;
```

Step 3: Import the helper file and call the getlogger() method to add logging statements to your tests

```
var log4jsGen = require("../Utilities/log4jsGen");
log4jsGen.getLogger().info("Testing Log4js");
```

Comment: bro .. you just copied my complete blog and pasted here :) without any credit too :)